# Java Chat Server

Tags: java, sockets, chat

FYI This is homework. I have to build a Java Chat server. I have been able to build a server which communicates with 1 client. But I need this to communicate with multiple users.

A user is supposed to type in the person's name they wish to talk to followed by a dash (-) and then the message to be sent. I am able to get users signed on but I am not able to get the list of users to print out or the messages to send to other users. Here is the server code:

```
/** 
    Threaded Server
*/

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class ThreadedServer
{
    public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        HashMap<String, Socket> users = new HashMap<String, Socket>( );
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5679);
        System.out.println( "THE CHAT SERVER HAS STARTED! =)" );
        while(true)
        {
            Socket client = server.accept();
            ThreadedServer ser = new ThreadedServer();
            ClientFromThread cft =ser.new ClientFromThread(client);
            String name = cft.getUserName();
            users.put( name, client );
            cft.giveUsersMap( users );
            //cft.giveOnlineUsers( ); //DOES NOT WORK YET!!!!
            System.out.println("Threaded server connected to " 
                        + client.getInetAddress() + "  USER: " + name );            
        } 

    }

    //***************************************************************************************************

    class ClientFromThread extends Thread
    {
        private Socket client;
        private Scanner fromClient;
        private PrintWriter toClient;
        private String userName;
        HashMap<String, Socket> users;

        public ClientFromThread( Socket c ) throws Exception
        {
            client = c;
            fromClient = new Scanner( client.getInputStream() );
            toClient = new PrintWriter( client.getOutputStream(), true );
            userName = getUser();
            start();
        }
        public void giveUsersMap( HashMap<String, Socket> users )
        {
            this.users = users;
        }

        //THIS DOESNT WORK YET... IT PRINTS THE FIRST LINE BUT NOT THE LIST
        public void giveOnlineUsers()
        {
            toClient.println("These users are currently online:");
            Set<String> userList = users.keySet();
            String[] userNames = null;
            userList.toArray( userNames );

            for( int i = 0; i< userNames.length; i++ )
            {
                toClient.println(userNames[i]);
            }
        }

        public String getUserName()
        {
            return userName;
        }

        private String getUser()
        {
            String s = "";
            while( (s.length() < 1) || (s == null) )
            {
                toClient.println("What is your first name? ");
                s=fromClient.nextLine().trim();
            }
            toClient.println("Thank You! Welcome to the chat room " + s + ".");
            return s.toUpperCase();
        }

        public void run() 
        {
            String s = null;
            String toUser;
            String mesg;

            while( (s=fromClient.nextLine().trim()) != null )
            {
                if( s.equalsIgnoreCase( "END" )) break;

                for( int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
                {
                    if( s.charAt(i) == '-' )
                    {
                        toUser = s.substring( 0, i ).trim().toUpperCase();
                        mesg = s.substring( i+1 ).trim();
                        Socket client = users.get( toUser );
                        try
                        {
                            ClientToThread ctt = new ClientToThread(client);
                            ctt.sendMesg( mesg, toUser );
                            ctt.start();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                        break;
                    }
                    if( (i+1) == s.length() )
                    {
                        toClient.println("Sorry the text was invalid. Please enter a user name " +
                                                     "followed by a dash (-) then your message.");
                    }
                }
            }
            try
            {
                fromClient.close();
                toClient.close();
                client.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }

    } //end class ClientFromThread

    //***************************************************************************************************

    class ClientToThread extends Thread
    {
        private Socket client;
        private PrintWriter toClient;
        private String mesg;

        public ClientToThread( Socket c ) throws Exception
        {
            client = c;
            toClient = new PrintWriter( client.getOutputStream(), true );
        }

        public void sendMesg( String mesg, String userName )
        {
            this.mesg = userName + ": " + mesg;
        }
        public void run() 
        {
            toClient.println(mesg);

            try
            {
                toClient.close();
                client.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }

    } //end class ClientToThread

    //***************************************************************************************************

} //end class ThreadedServer
```

Here is the Client code"

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class ReverseClient 
{
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    String line = null;
    Socket server= new Socket( "10.0.2.103", 5679);
    System.out.println( "Connected to host: " + server.getInetAddress() );
    BufferedReader fromServer = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()) );
    PrintWriter toServer = new PrintWriter( server.getOutputStream(), true );
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader( 
                new InputStreamReader(System.in) );
    while( (line=input.readLine()) !=null )
    {
        toServer.println(line);
        System.out.println( fromServer.readLine() );
    }
    fromServer.close();
    toServer.close();
    input.close();
    server.close();

}   
}
```

Here is the console output (the top is the server, bottom is the client):
[image]

I am getting errors (as shown in the image above) and the messages are not sending. Any suggestions on how to take care of these issues?

Comment: I am getting errors (as shown in the image above) and the messages are not sending. Any suggestions on how to take care of these issue

Comment: post the client code, so I can try to get this example running and try to help you out.

Comment: I added the client code. You will need to change the ip address to suit your network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I found this to be a problem, but I don't think this is the only problem..

This will help the NoSuchElementException
On around line 90 Change this...

```
while( (s=fromClient.nextLine().trim()) != null )
{
```

to this...

```
while(fromClient.hasNext())
{
   s = fromClient.nextLine().trim();
```

OK just found another problem in ClientToThread.run()...  You are closing the client connections after you send the first message.  I commented them both out and it seems to be working a little better.

```
public void run()
  {
     toClient.println(mesg);
     try {
        //toClient.close();
        //client.close();
     }
     catch (Exception e)  {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
```

Comment: ok. I fixed that. I cant believe I didnt catch that. That part was copied from an example my professor gave.

Comment: now I'm getting...  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed on this line in the ReverseClient...
System.out.println( fromServer.readLine() );

Comment: Ok. That took care of the errors... Now the message are sending but they are not sending to the receiver in the order that they were sent... and the receiver doesn't get it until they send a message...

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is with the parsing of the message from the user.

You loop through the string, and it has one of two options, either the character is a dash or it is invalid.

So, ideally, you should be getting an invalid message for the number of a characters in the username before the dash.

You should use String.indexOf to determine where the dash is, and then split the message into it's two parts, and if the result of indexOf is -1 then it is an invalid message.